# Quickfix increases hight when opening vertical window

Tags: vim

I have a quickfix for the `ctrlP` vim plugin. When I decide to open a window vertically (by pressing v) from one of the searches, the height of the Quickfix increases. This keeps happening as I open more windows.

How can I solve that? I don't see anything in the configuration to do that.